# unique_together foreign key object properties

Tags: django, django-models

I've got two models: Common and ARecord.  ARecord has a ForeignKey relationship to Common.  I want to ensure that ARecord is unique with a combination of items from ARecord and Common.

```
class Common(models.Model):
    NAIC_number = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    file_location_state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    file_location_code = models.CharField(max_length=2)

class ARecord(models.Model):
    common = models.ForeignKey(Common)
    coverage_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    record_type = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('coverage_code', 'common__NAIC_number')
```

However, when I attempt to access the foreign key object property via the usual double underscore, I get a model validation error.

```
`arecord.arecord: "unique_together" refers to common__NAIC_number, a field that doesn't exist. Check your syntax.`
```

This seems like it should be possible and, a slightly different question was asked that indicates  [it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297800/django-unique-together-for-on-sub-class-model-for-parent-attribute) , but perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Manoj implies, you can't do this with `unique_together`, because that is a database constraint and the sort of thing you want can't be done with database constraints.

Instead, you want do this programmatically, probably via [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/), which will ensure that no instances are created that violate your constraint.

Comment: That makes sense.  Unfortunately, I'm running Django v1.0 so no validators for me.  And even if I could, I'm not inclined to do it that way; seems like it would be waaay to easy to jack up my database during a save.  Common is saved before ARecord, so Common could be successfully saved before I get to the validation point. Then I'd have to delete Common, but which one?  Anyway, I'm going to move coverage_code up to the Common class.  I thought I'd have to do that anyway, but I was hoping for a little magic.  Alas.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense to me. The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) defines `unique_together` thus:

> This is a list of lists of fields that must be unique when considered together. It's used in the Django admin and **is enforced at the database level** (i.e., the appropriate UNIQUE statements are included in the CREATE TABLE statement).

(Emphasis added)

I don't know how an `UNIQUE` statement can be added at the database level for such a case (using one column in the current table and another in a different table accessed through a foreign key). I hope those who know better about databases will correct me if I am wrong.