# Ensuring uniqueness across multiple models Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have three models: Account, Employee and Company. An account can be of the type employee or company and a OneToOne Field relates an account to either an employee or company record. See models below:

```
class Account(auth_models.AbstractBaseUser):

     username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

     ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
         ("company", "Company"),
         ("employee", "Employee"),
     )

     account_type = models.CharField(
         choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES,
         default="EMPLOYEE",
         blank=False,
         null=False,
         max_length=10,
      )
     date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date Joined", auto_now_add=True)
     is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
     is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

     USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
     REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["account_type"]
```

I then have the Company model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
```

Then I have the Employee model, where an Employee is also related to the company it is employed by:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
     date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
     employer = models.ForeignKey(
         Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employees"
     )
     employment_start_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
     employment_end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to make sure usernames are unique within the company, but not unique within the whole web app. So there can be multiple users with the same username, but not within the same company.
For example:
Suppose a user created an account with the `username John Smith` with the `company ABC` that will be fine.

But then if another user created an account with the `username John Smith` but in the `company DEF` that will also be allowed as it is in another company.

But if someone tries to make an account with the `username John Smith` within the `company ABC`, that will not be allowed as it already exists with that company

Solutions I've thought of so far:

1. Adding a company field to the Account model - the issue with this being that an Account with the account_type "Company" would not have a value for the company field it would be illogical. Also it would be illogical as via relationships you can find the company an employee belongs to in the Employee table/model.
2. Getting the "employees" field from the Company model and checking if the user already exists within that field as it is exclusive to the company - I have no idea how to implement something like this.
3. Using emails instead - I wanted to originally do this, but people within my team want us to use usernames instead as not everyone interacting with the system will have an email.

Any help on how I could implement something like this would be great. Thanks :)

P.S I'm using Postgres

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? You could probably enact this with a database-level check...

Comment: @AKX I'm using Postgres

Comment: So in fact, wouldn't an [uniqueness constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) on `("employer", "user__username")` on `Employee` be enough?

Comment: @AKX The issue is that the Account record gets created before the employer record. So I don't want to create accounts that can't be linked if the username is already taken and I don't find out until the Employee record is created. Or am I thinking of this incorrectly?

Comment: Create them in a transaction, and both will be rolled back if the whole shebang is invalid.

Comment: @AKX you've lost me a bit there. I like the idea of it being rolled back. Could you explain a bit more or send me a link so I can understand it a bit better

Comment: [See here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/transactions/) `with transaction.atomic(): user = User.objects.create_user(username=...); employee = Employee.objects.create(user=..., employer=...)` – if the second database call fails (due to invalid data or a constraint failure, like here), then the user creation is also "forgotten" as far as the database is concerned.

Comment: That aside, I think you _may_ run into some issues if you remove the global uniqueness constraint on the Django user's Username field.

Comment: @AKX so does that mean its not possible as it messes with the django authentication backend

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you'll probably need to adapt login views at the very least so you can select the correct company, etc. since an username is no longer unique.

Comment: Why does the company need an `Account`? In the end is it not a member of the company who uses the account? So can it not be better modeled as an employee (better termed as user) who has administrative rights on the company by adding some attribute / field for the same?

Comment: And since you mentioned postgres, this [package](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) just might solve your problem, since then you can have the companies in separate schemas.

Comment: I've thought of an even simpler solution. Regardless of the account type the account has a company, given this you just need to have a foreign key from account to company. You can then remove the FK from the employee to the company model and also remove the one to one field from company to account.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I've mentioned that yesterday (16h ago) on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73691342/7109869).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Adding a company field to the Account model - the issue with this being that an Account with the account_type "Company" would not have a value for the company field it would be illogical. Also it would be illogical as via relationships you can find the company an employee belongs to in the Employee table/model.

Why would a Company have an empty company field? OP can have it with the company field as well since OP has the field `account_type` to distinguish between the types of Accounts (generally I prefer to have fields similar to `account_type` as `Boolean`, so something like `is_company`).

Also, OP can't find the company an employee belongs to from the Employee model if OP removes the employer and take that the employer is implicit in the company of the Account. So, if OP goes with this approach, then remove it as well. (Well, OP could but OP would then have to go through the user/Account).

As a way to clarify [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73687427/ensuring-uniqueness-across-multiple-models-django/73691342?noredirect=1#comment130156745_73691342), like I explained in previously, one can have the `Account` model with

- `is_company` `BooleanField` -> this will tell which kind of account you have.
- `company` `ForeignKey` -> this will tell the company for both types of accounts.

The `Company` model with

- `name`
- other company information (do not add the `user` `OneToOneField` here)

Then in `Employee` one won't need the employer since one can infer that from the `Account`. But onr will have to add

- `user` `OneToOneField` -> Because one account has zero or one and only one employee.

---

> 2. Getting the "employees" field from the Company model and checking if the user already exists within that field as it is exclusive to the company - I have no idea how to implement something like this.

Initially I though one could use [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) (or [`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint)) to the Employee model, like

```
class Meta:
        unique_together = [["employer", "user__username"]]
```

Yet, as per [Abdul Aziz Barkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73687427/ensuring-uniqueness-across-multiple-models-django/73691342#comment130131142_73691342)

> you cannot create constraints spanning relations / tables

So, a workaround can be to [override the model's `save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) to perform the validation. [Read more about overriding model predefined methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).

Still, this doesn't solve the fact that an Account is created first than an Employee ATM.

Since to create an Account OP is already checking for a unique username, the uniqueness is being enforced previous to the Employee.

As [AKX mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73687427/ensuring-uniqueness-across-multiple-models-django/73691342#comment130123094_73687427), there's a workaround, more precisely, creating the Account and Employee in a [transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/transactions/#module-django.db.transaction). That implies OP is able to remove `unique=True` in Accounts, which, according to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser)

> The field must be unique (i.e., have unique=True set in its definition), unless you use a custom authentication backend that can support non-unique usernames.

---

> 3. Using emails instead - I wanted to originally do this, but people within my team want us to use usernames instead as not everyone interacting with the system will have an email.

Well people within OP's team might not be aware of the implications such request brings. Even though a framework like Django brings flexibility in various levels, such as database migrations, it also has its ways which might be unknown to your team. You can have a meeting and present the different options that OP considered and it's implications and I'm sure they are able to understand.

Comment: `unique_together = [["employer", "user__username"]]` that won't work as constraints can't traverse relations.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat [Here's an example of that working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2297915/7109869)

Comment: That answer is from 2010 when `unique_together` might have been implemented on the Python side, if you read this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743932/14991864) on the same question it states why this isn't possible. `unique_together` is implemented by creating a unique constraint in the database, you cannot create constraints spanning relations / tables as I mention in my previous comment.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thank you! If you didn't commit your time to comment this, I would still be thinking that it was possible.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres In regards to the first solution with why can't a company account have a company associated, I checked out this article when designing the system. Check out the flow chart: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html A company account can't have a company associated with it as it is associated with it via the OneToOne Field in the company model

Comment: @TheSunbathingCrow Oh I didn't see the one-to-one relationship in Company user field. OP can remove that one and simply use the company one as a Foreign key in Account

Comment: I have two types of users: Company and Employee. Each has to have an Account record and Employees belong to a Company and an Account. What should I do?

Comment: @TheSunbathingCrow check the edit in the first part.

Comment: @TheSunbathingCrow Note that it is one of the possible paths.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres I like the first idea, I'm going to implement that. In the Account model I am doing it so that username and company are unique together. I then will have a REST Framework API that will generate an auth_token, do I need to change anything there

Comment: @TheSunbathingCrow It depends on how you implement it. My recommendation is for you to try and if another question pops up, feel free to ask here in StackOverflow. If not me, then most likely another great developer will be ready to help.